# VW Golf 2001 Mk4 Diesel ASR Engine Problem

Tags: engine, electrical, vw, diesel, egr

I've spent a crazy amount of money on my car lately and I still have the same problem.

I've replaced the:

1. Catalyst Converter
2. Radiator
3. Starter Motor
4. EGR Valve
5. Track Rod ends & Wheel Bearings

The problem I have still is that when I start the car in the morning or after work.. So the car has been resting for more than 7/8 hours. At around 1500-2000 revolutions the ASR light comes on a the engine starts to shake like made. Leaving the car to warm-up for 10 minutes or so sometimes cures the problem. And  once I try to pull ofF from low revs with the ASR stuck on.. The car shudders. Can anyone identify what is happening?

I'm so fed up of the it. I bought it for around £2200 and i've probably spent that much on repairs.. labour costs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Classic fuel starvation, probably caused by an old, gummed up fuel filter.  Replace the fuel filter and purge the injectors (remove them from the head, crank the engine a few times and clean the injectors thoroughly).

If this doesn't solve things get the fault codes read as it could be something like a problem with the injector loom.

Comment: From just reading this, it gives me hope that the car is not on it's last legs... I'll forward this to a mechanic and get them to do it! :) Thanks! I'll update with any info.

Comment: But does this explain the ASR issue?

Comment: Yes, the ASR light will go crazy when the car is running with low power because it's a fly by wire throttle and it's expecting to see much more "go" than it's actually seeing.